# Trying to add a new module to a project. Fails to read script

Tags: android, gradle, module

I am trying to add a epub reader library to a project I have already created. The library I am trying to add to my project as a moduel is the Folio Reader Library (https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android). I have downloaded this library on my computer and have tried adding it through File -> New -> Import Module. However, during the process I receive this error:

```
ERROR: Could not read script 'C:\Users\Vasko\Desktop\Knigoteka2\config\quality\quality.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

This file is located in the build.gradle file of the Folio Reader Library.

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

ext {
bintrayRepo = 'maven'
bintrayName = 'folioreader'

publishedGroupId = 'com.folioreader'
libraryName = 'FolioReader'
artifact = 'folioreader'

libraryDescription = 'An epub reader for Android'

siteUrl = 'https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android'
gitUrl = 'https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android.git'

libraryVersion = versions.folioreaderSdk

developerId = 'mobisystech'
developerName = 'Folio Reader'
developerEmail = 'mahavir@codetoart.com'

licenseName = 'FreeBSD License'
licenseUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Documentation_License#License'
allLicenses = ["FreeBSD"]
}

android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion versions.androidCompileSdk

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion versions.androidMinSdk
    targetSdkVersion versions.androidTargetSdk
    versionCode versions.projectVersionCode
    versionName versions.projectVersionName
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    lintConfig file("lint.xml")
}

checkstyle {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
}

apply from: '../folioreader/bintray/installv1.gradle'
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$versions.appcompat"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$versions.constraintLayout"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$versions.recyclerview"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$versions.material"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.25'
implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'

//Kotlin
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$versions.kotlin"

implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$versions.jackson"
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$versions.jackson"
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$versions.jackson"
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$versions.jackson"
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$versions.gson"

implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$versions.retrofit"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:$versions.retrofit"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$versions.retrofit"

// R2 modules
api("com.github.codetoart:r2-shared-kotlin:$versions.r2SharedKotlin") {
    changing = true
}
api("com.github.codetoart:r2-streamer-kotlin:$versions.r2StreamerKotlin") {
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-api"
    changing = true
}

// Only ReflectionUtils in Spring framework is used
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.19.RELEASE'

// Lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle- 
extensions:$versions.lifecycle"
}
apply from: '../folioreader/bintray/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build.gradle` script is looking for some files which it can't find in your project's directory structure. Looking at your error messages and the github repository, it seems you need to do the following:

1. Download the `config` folder from the [github repository](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android/tree/master/config)
2. Place it in your project's directory (`Knigoteka2` in your case), parallel to where you have placed the `folioreader` library module

Comment: Yup that solved the problem. However a new one arises immediately after it: 
ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.

Comment: Cool. Maybe ask a new question? I might be able to take a look at that.

Comment: Need to wait 90 more minutes before I can post again.

Comment: here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847715/trying-to-add-module-to-project-plugin-with-id-kotlin-android-not-found?noredirect=1#comment100246360_56847715