# Trying to add module to project. Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found

Tags: android, gradle, module

I am trying to add a epub reader library to a project I have already created. The library I am trying to add to my project as a moduel is the Folio Reader Library (https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android). I have downloaded this library on my computer and have tried adding it through File -> New -> Import Module. However, during the process I receive this error:

```
ERROR: Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.
```

This file is located in the build.gradle file of the Folio Reader Library.

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

ext {
bintrayRepo = 'maven'
bintrayName = 'folioreader'

publishedGroupId = 'com.folioreader'
libraryName = 'FolioReader'
artifact = 'folioreader'

libraryDescription = 'An epub reader for Android'

siteUrl = 'https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android'
gitUrl = 'https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android.git'

libraryVersion = versions.folioreaderSdk

developerId = 'mobisystech'
developerName = 'Folio Reader'
developerEmail = 'mahavir@codetoart.com'

licenseName = 'FreeBSD License'
licenseUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Documentation_License#License'
allLicenses = ["FreeBSD"]
}

android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion versions.androidCompileSdk

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion versions.androidMinSdk
    targetSdkVersion versions.androidTargetSdk
    versionCode versions.projectVersionCode
    versionName versions.projectVersionName
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    lintConfig file("lint.xml")
}

checkstyle {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
}

apply from: '../folioreader/bintray/installv1.gradle'
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$versions.appcompat"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$versions.constraintLayout"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$versions.recyclerview"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$versions.material"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.25'
implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'

//Kotlin
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$versions.kotlin"

implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$versions.jackson"
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$versions.jackson"
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$versions.jackson"
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$versions.jackson"
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$versions.gson"

implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$versions.retrofit"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:$versions.retrofit"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$versions.retrofit"

// R2 modules
api("com.github.codetoart:r2-shared-kotlin:$versions.r2SharedKotlin") {
    changing = true
}
api("com.github.codetoart:r2-streamer-kotlin:$versions.r2StreamerKotlin") {
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-api"
    changing = true
}

// Only ReflectionUtils in Spring framework is used
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.19.RELEASE'

// Lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle- 
extensions:$versions.lifecycle"
}
apply from: '../folioreader/bintray/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

I have tried some of the answers posted here but they do not work.
How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:

I added

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.4-3"
```

in my dependencies and have received the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'versions' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.
```

it is occuring on line 20 on the same build.gradle file:

```
libraryVersion = versions.folioreaderSdk
```

updating to newer version does not work:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.40"
```

Comment: Why would you want to add a module? From what I see, you only need to add dependencies to your `build.gradle`

Comment: I have been tasked to do so.

Comment: Then check that module `build.gradle` and try adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` to it

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the library structure on Github, it seems you need to do the following

- Go to *YOUR* project level build.gradle file (not the module level build.gradle)
- Look at the repositories, dependencies in the Library's [project level build.gradle file](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android/blob/master/build.gradle) and copy them over to *YOUR* project level build.gradle file (including the kotlin-gradle-plugin dependency)

Note: in case you haven't worked with `External` variables syntax before, you can find those variables for this library in the [root directory of the github repository](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android/blob/master/versions.gradle).

In this case, writing

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$versions.kotlin"`
```

will resolve to the following (you can directly write this in your project)

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.11"
```

Comment: Should I copy only the repositories and dependencies?

Comment: Thats where i would start. If there are more errors, i would follow the errors and bring over other stuff.

Comment: You suggestion was correct. I replaced all of the @versions.kotlin external variable assignments with the values assigned to them in the library's versions.gradle file. And now it seems to work.

Comment: There is a continuation to my problem here if you are interested in taking a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850745/trying-to-add-module-to-project-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-versionname

Comment: I believe you were able to solve that one yourself, we're getting there! :-)

Comment: Yup, that was the last one, no more errors module was successfully integrated! :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following in the main "build.gradle" file of the project:

```
`allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
        }
    }
}`
```